# fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD: Could not send response to the client,java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) #444

Tags: android, nanohttpd

i am using NanoHttpd to serve the videos in my android application but i am getting the below error please help me.

```
    fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD: Could not send response to the client
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:546)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:515)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response$ChunkedOutputStream.write(NanoHTTPD.java:1369)
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1620)
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1593)
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1580)
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1550)
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:937)
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:192)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:206)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:513)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504) 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37) 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response$ChunkedOutputStream.write(NanoHTTPD.java:1369) 
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1620) 
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1593) 
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1580) 
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1550) 
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:937) 
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:192) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Some Suggestions says to add below code to solve the issue and i added as well but no results
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder() .permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); } 
 Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: In some blogs someone suggested to use the below: if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }  But no the problem not solved.

Comment: Can you add that to your post?

Comment: i have added it to the post @Noel Widmer, please help me,